# Cómo muestro una imagen guardada en una carpeta en el servidor tomcat en un img en html?

Tags: java, html, jsp, tomcat

Tengo una app web con jsp. En mi servidor tomcat tengo una carpeta llamada TemporalesImagenes y dentro de ella hay imágenes que quiero mostrar en mi app.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo hago para mostrar una imagen en una página html de mi proyecto usando la etiqueta img?

```
<img src="">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si pones la **/** al principio en un **apache tomcat** se refiere a la **webapp/ROOT**

puedes usar **request.getContextPath()** para sacar el contexto de tu app, y poner :

**request.getContextPath() + /TemporalesImagenes/...**

lo que te dara como resultado :

**/TemporalesImagenes/...** si estas en ROOT
o
**/webappname/TemporalesImagenes/...**

Tambien otra opción puedes referenciar una carpeta de contenido estático, xml, logs, imágenes, etc en la url de tu aplicación.

Para hacer esto deber añadir la propiedad de contexto  **docBase** en tu **server.xml** file called , ejemplo:

```
   <Context docBase="/ruta/a/mis/archivos" path="/MY-APP/files"/>
```

El archivo **servers.xml** está en el la carpeta **conf** justo debajo del la carpeta donde hayamos instalado el **tomcat**  ejemplo: **tomcat6.0/conf** o si estamos usando un IDE como eclipse debemos ir al directorio donde esta la configuración del servidor normalmente está en el mismo workspace con el nombre **Servers** (en eclipse).

Ejemplo de configuración cambiando el **server.xml** de un workspace de eclipse IDE. La aplicación se llama MY-APP.

```
 <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" 
       unpackWARs="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" 
               directory="logs" 
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" 
               prefix="localhost_access_log." 
               suffix=".txt"/>

        <Context docBase="/home/ubuntu/content/" path="/MY-APP/img"/>
        <!-- all the files in folder are linked to MY-APP/img  -->
        <Context docBase="MY-APP" 
                 path="/MY-APP" 
                 reloadable="true" 
                 source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:MY-APP"/>
 </Host>
```

En este ejemplo, el servidor configurado en el puerto 8080 ya se puede ver la imagen que tengo en la carpeta /home/ubuntu/content/myimage.jpg desde la url http://localhost:8080/MY-APP/img/myimage.jpg

Y en tu etiqueta **HTML** tendrías:

```
<img src="https://localhost:8080/MY-APP/img/myimage.jpg">
```

Comment: Hola! muchas gracias por tu respuesta.
request.getContextPath() + /TemporalesImagenes/.. me da al final /webappname/TemporalesImagenes/... justo como indicas, lo cuál no me sirve. Trataré con la otra forma y vuelvo

Comment: Estoy utilizando netbenas IDE y usa directamente mi carpeta de instalación tomcat (que es la que estás viendo en las imágenes), cómo debería configurar el último Context que pones ahí donde source hace referencia al eclipse?